# How to force the race condition in transaction in django tests?

Tags: python, django, testing, transactions, race-condition

Is there a way to run the django tests using multiple threads and force the race condition? I want to make sure that the code path that handles the transaction errors is executed. To be slightly more specific, I want to be able to spawn 2 threads that will try to perform the same action on the database, with one of them succeeding and the other one failing. I'm using the test framework that is in django.

Python pseudocode:

```
def some_method():
  try
    with transaction.atomic():
      objectA = get_object_from_db()
      objectA.delete()
  except Error:
    # error handling code to be run

  
class TestClass(TransactionalTestCase):
  def test_some_method():
    # run two threads and make sure that the race condition was present and some_method recovered successfully
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm reading you want to cover the path where you handle the exception. I'm asking you this question: do you really need it to be triggered in the case of multithreads race condition or do you just want to make sure that in the case it happens it does the right thing ?

Here's what I would do:

```
import unittest
import mock


# added just mimic django's orm for the purpose of the demo
class QuerySet(object):
  def delete(self):
    pass

def get_object_from_db():
  return QuerySet()

def some_method():
  try:
    objectA = get_object_from_db()
    objectA.delete()
    return True # this should be whatever you want to do in case it worked
  except Exception: # I would look up and check what ever error the django orm is raising.
    return False # this should be whatever you want to do in case it didn't work

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_some_method_in_case_it_worked(self):
    self.assertEqual(some_method(), True)

  def test_some_method_in_case_it_did_not_work(self):
    with mock.patch('__main__.get_object_from_db') as mocked_get_object_from_db:
      mocked_get_object_from_db.side_effect = RuntimeError('a message')
      self.assertEqual(some_method(), False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

mock is now part of the standard library. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock

Doing this is saving you from having flapper tests. You know the ones that randomly fail.

Answer (score 2):

**Race condition** causes 2 anomalies **lost update** or **write skew**. So  with **2 threads**, you can test if **lost update** or **write skew** occurs in some isolation levels.

I created 2 sets of code to test **lost update** or **write skew** with the default isolation level **READ COMMITTED** on **PostgreSQL** as shown below:

I explain about:

- **lost update** and **write skew** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew/73847878#73847878)
- which **anomaly** occurs in which **isolation level** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165438/dirty-reads-in-postgres/73995828#73995828)

### <**Lost update**>

First, I created **`store_product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, I created and ran the test code of **lost update** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from threading import Thread
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "SELECT")
                product = Product.objects.get(id=2)
                print(product.id, product.name, product.stock)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Product.objects.filter(id=2).update(stock=13)
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "SELECT")
                product = Product.objects.get(id=2)
                print(product.id, product.name, product.stock)
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Product.objects.filter(id=2).update(stock=16)                
                flow[0] = "Step 8"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 8":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                break
        break

def call_transcations(request): 
    flow = ["Step 1"]

    thread1 = Thread(target=transaction1, args=(flow,), daemon=True)
    thread2 = Thread(target=transaction2, args=(flow,), daemon=True)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

    return HttpResponse("Call_transcations")
```

Then, **lost update** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **lost update** occurs:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT # Reads the same row
2 Orange 20
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT # Reads the same row
2 Orange 20
T1 Step 5 UPDATE # Writes "stock"
T1 Step 6 COMMIT # And commits the write
T2 Step 7 UPDATE # Overwrites "stock"
T2 Step 8 COMMIT # And commits the overwrite
```

And also, I could get **the SQL query logs of PostgreSQL** below. You can check [**how to log SQL queries on PostgreSQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

```
[20504]: BEGIN
[20504]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
         FROM "store_product" 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[3840]: BEGIN
[3840]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
        FROM "store_product" 
        WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
        LIMIT 21
[20504]: UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 13 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[20504]: COMMIT
[3840]: UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 16 
        WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[3840]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 13 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 16 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update occurs. |

Next, because **lost update** doesn't occur in `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level in PostgreSQL so I set `REPEATABLE READ` with **psql** as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE postgres SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'REPEATABLE READ';
```

Then again, I ran the code above then, **lost update** didn't occur because at `T2 Step 7`, update was refused occurring 2 exceptions as shown below:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT
2 Orange 20
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT
2 Orange 20
T1 Step 5 UPDATE
T1 Step 6 COMMIT
T2 Step 7 UPDATE    # ↓↓ 2 exceptions occurred ↓↓
psycopg2.errors.SerializationFailure: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

And also, update was refused occurring 1 error and the 2nd transaction was rollbacked according to **the SQL query logs of PostgreSQL** below:

```
[14072]: BEGIN
[14072]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
         FROM "store_product" 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[1834]: BEGIN
[1834]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
        FROM "store_product" 
        WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
        LIMIT 21
[14072]: UPDATE "store_product" 
         SET "stock" = 13 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[14072]: COMMIT
[1834] ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update # Here
[1834] STATEMENT: UPDATE "store_product" 
                  SET "stock" = 16 
                  WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[1834]: ROLLBACK # Here
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 13 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 16 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** **ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update** | **T2 cannot update `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`ROLLBACK;`** | **T2 rollbacks.** #### *Lost update doesn't occur. |

### <**Write skew**>

First, I created **`store_doctor` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`on_call`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_doctor` table:

| id | name | on_call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** | **True** |
| **2** | **Lisa** | **True** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    on_call = models.BooleanField()
```

Then, I created and ran the test code of **write skew** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

# ...

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                print("T1", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                print("T1", flow[0], "SELECT")
                doctor_count = Doctor.objects.filter(on_call=True).count()
                print(doctor_count)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                print("T1", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Doctor.objects.filter(id=1).update(on_call=False)
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                print("T1", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                print("T2", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                print("T2", flow[0], "SELECT")
                doctor_count = Doctor.objects.filter(on_call=True).count()
                print(doctor_count)
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                print("T2", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Doctor.objects.filter(id=2).update(on_call=False)
                flow[0] = "Step 8"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 8":
                print("T2", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                break
        break

# ...
```

Then, **write skew** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **write skew** occurs:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT # Reads the same data
2 
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT # Reads the same data
2
T1 Step 5 UPDATE # Writes 'False' to John's "on_call" 
T1 Step 6 COMMIT # And commits the write
T2 Step 7 UPDATE # Writes 'False' to Lisa's "on_call" 
T2 Step 8 COMMIT # And commits the write
```

And also, I could get **the SQL query logs of PostgreSQL** below:

```
[11252]: BEGIN
[11252]: SELECT COUNT(*) 
         AS "__count" 
         FROM "store_doctor" 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[2368]: BEGIN
[2368]: SELECT COUNT(*) 
        AS "__count" 
        FROM "store_doctor" 
        WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[11252]: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
         SET "on_call" = false 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1
[11252]: COMMIT
[2368]: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
        SET "on_call" = false 
        WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2
[2368]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2` so John can take a rest.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** | **T2 reads `2` so Lisa can take a rest.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1;`** |  | **T1 updates `True` to `False` which means John takes a rest.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `True` to `False` which means Lisa takes a rest.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### John and Lisa both take a rest. #### *Write skew occurs. |

Next, because **write skew** doesn't occur in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level in PostgreSQL so I set `SERIALIZABLE` with **psql** as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE postgres SET DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION TO 'SERIALIZABLE';
```

Then again, I ran the code above then, **write skew** didn't occur because at `T2 Step 7`, update was refused occurring 2 exceptions as shown below:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT
2
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT
2
T1 Step 5 UPDATE
T1 Step 6 COMMIT
T2 Step 7 UPDATE    # ↓↓ 2 exceptions occurred ↓↓
psycopg2.errors.SerializationFailure: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
```

And also, update was refused occurring 1 error and the 2nd transaction was rollbacked according to **the SQL query logs of PostgreSQL** below:

```
[80642]: BEGIN
[80642]: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" 
         FROM "store_doctor" 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[4244]: BEGIN
[4244]: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" 
        FROM "store_doctor" 
        WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[80642]: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
         SET "on_call" = false 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1
[80642]: COMMIT
[4244] ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions # Here
[4244] DETAIL: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write.
[4244] HINT: The transaction might succeed if retried.
[4244] STATEMENT: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
                  SET "on_call" = false 
                  WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2
[4244]: ROLLBACK # Here
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2` so John can take a rest.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** | **T2 reads `2` so Lisa can take a rest.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1;`** |  | **T1 updates `True` to `False` which means John takes a rest.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2;`** **ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions** | **T2 cannot update `True` to `False` which means Lisa cannot take a rest.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`ROLLBACK;`** | **T2 rollbacks.** #### Only John takes a rest. #### *Write skew doesn't occur. |